# Error with laravel filemanager

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, file-manager

I'm using https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager

```
OS System & Version: Linux devstaff-ubuntu 4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016 x86_64
Laravel Version: v5.4.25
File Manager Version: v1.7.5
imagick Extension: Not Install
gd Extension: Install
```

I can't create folders or uploads images in production (digital ocean, LEMP STACK) , i think is because one missing parameter from the url.

```
Request URL:http://l200.screativa.com/laravel-filemanager/newfolder?working_dir=%2F1&type=&name=aaaa&_=1497045494369

Query string parameters 
working_dir:/1
type:
name:aaaa
_:1497045494369
```

Is this related to any server config (nginx)? Because in my localserver works.

I will appreciate any help and sorry for the bad english!

Ps: if anyone can recommend me other filemanager.

Thanks.